# Error when installing tideSDK developer 1.4.2 on fedora 13

Tags: titanium, tidesdk

i have installed tideSDK 1.3.1-beta on my machine
File path is "user/.tidesdk"..
then tried to install  tideSDK developer 1.4.2 i got following error message.

**Couldn't load file:/home/mareeswari/TideSDK-Developer-1.4.2-linux-x86/runtime/1.3.1-beta/libtide.so, error: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /home/mareeswari/TideSDK-Developer-1.4.2-linux-x86/runtime/1.3.1-beta/libtide.so)**

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid crash. Its because TideSDK does not support fedora / redhat family yet. The underlying binaries are compiled for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully got Tide Developer working on Fedora 18.

I had a similar issue to you, however it was complaining about libpng12, so installed the libpng12 and libpng12-devel and it worked fine.

Hope this helps someone